# python conditional grouped ffill

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, fillna

```
In [179]: test = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4], 'B': [-999, np.nan, np.nan, 3
     ...: , np.nan, -999, np.nan, 5,-999,np.nan, 3]})                                     

In [180]: test                                                                            
Out[180]: 
    A      B
0   1 -999.0
1   1    NaN
2   1    NaN
3   2    3.0
4   2    NaN
5   2 -999.0
6   2    NaN
7   3    5.0
8   3 -999.0
9   4    NaN
10  4    3.0
```

I want to fill nan values in column B if the precedent value is -999 grouped by column A

desired result:

```
Out[181]: 
    A      B
0   1 -999.0
1   1 -999.0
2   1 -999.0
3   2    3.0
4   2    NaN
5   2 -999.0
6   2 -999.0
7   3    5.0
8   3 -999.0
9   4    NaN
10  4    3.0
```

I used an iterrows to check each row but ... my real df has 1M lines

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fillvals = df.groupby('A').ffill()
df['B'].fillna(fillvals[fillvals.eq(-999)]['B'], inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
    A      B
0   1 -999.0
1   1 -999.0
2   1 -999.0
3   2    3.0
4   2    NaN
5   2 -999.0
6   2 -999.0
7   3    5.0
8   3 -999.0
9   4    NaN
10  4    3.0
```

---

`df.groupby('A').ffill()` will fill any `NaN` value with the previous values, keep a copy of that frame.

`fillvals[fillvals.eq(-999)]['B'] to filter the indices that are only`-999`, i.e., the preceding value.

Use `fillna` to fill these `-999` from the filtered frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
test['B'] = (
    test['B'].fillna(test.groupby('A').B.ffill().where(lambda x: x.eq(-999)))
)

    A   B
0   1   -999.0
1   1   -999.0
2   1   -999.0
3   2   3.0
4   2   NaN
5   2   -999.0
6   2   -999.0
7   3   5.0
8   3   -999.0
9   4   NaN
10  4   3.0
```